# How to readOnly or cancel changeDate event on Bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap datepicker to show a calendar, but I don't want any human interaction.
It must be a read only calendar.

I try to disable onchange event, but it don't work:

**Edited to clarify:**

```js
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker();
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker().on("changeDate", function (ev) {
 return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div id="myDatePicker" style="border: 1px solid gray; display: inline-block;"></div>
```

**Expanded:**

The calendar is colored in certain dates, but this is not the problem. I want to show calendar data, but I need to avoid that the user can change the selected date or month. I want static data and no human interaction.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you shouldn't use a date "picker" if you want to "Show" a date.

Comment: Interesting question. So you want a display "like" datepicker... But no select interaction. Should the calendar display already known events? Or just a simple empty calendar? Can you be more specific about the usage?

Comment: I edited you snippet in order to make it work "a little". So that display we can see now... It's what you want? But in what context? Since no selection is needed, is the input field useful (could be hidden)? What's the use of the calendar?

Comment: Maybe you can disable all dates, just use: `daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` option ([doc here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#daysofweekdisabled)). I agree with previous comments, additional info about your scenario can ben useful.

Comment: Hey! would this be enought for your use ? http://www.plus2net.com/html_tutorial/html_calendar.php

Comment: Thanks for your responses and questions. I want to show a calendar with certains days colored depending on a status array in the simplest way. Also, I show 12 months in 12 calendars (one year), and for this reason I don't want that the user change the month. Maybe make my own calendar is better, but slower to develop, for this reason I trying Bootstarp-datepicker, but if it not posible, I take the @LouysPatriceBessette way. Thanks to all for your time!

Comment: Okay... "certain days colored" is a requirement. The link I gave you will not do. Here is [a link for you to read](http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/highlight-particular-dates-jquery-ui-datepicker/)... Add this to the @VincenzoC comment and you will be near a solution. ;) Feel free to EDIT your question in order to clarify it with your requirements... Else, you are really risking a close vote as *"unclear what you're asking"*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LouysPatriceBessette, but the colored is not a problem and a minor requeriment. I avoid it on the main exposition to simplify the question. I only want to avoid human interaction. No change selected date or month. That's the question. I edited the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an efficient way to "prevent" any mouse event on the calendar.

The trick is as simple as setting another "mask" `div` above the calendar, using `z-index`.

```js
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker();

// Get the calendar dimention and position.
var calendar={};
calendar.top=$("#myDatePicker").offset().top;
calendar.left=$("#myDatePicker").offset().left;
calendar.height=$("#myDatePicker").outerHeight();
calendar.width=$("#myDatePicker").outerWidth();
//console.log( JSON.stringify(calendar) );

// Apply it to a mask "over" the calendar.
$("#mask").css(calendar);
```

```css
#mask{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div id="myDatePicker" style="border: 1px solid gray; display: inline-block;"></div>
<div id="mask"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply remove all events

```
 $('#bookingsCalendar').find('.day').removeClass('day');

 dp.on('changeMonth', function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#bookingsCalendar').find('.day').removeClass('day');
        }, 100);
        
    });
```